# How to pull all the contributer users records and order by Designation (which is users meta data)?

Tags: users, meta-query, user-meta

I want to show all the contributors by the Designation. Following code is only pull the records and order by ID But I need to data order by Designation:

```
function contributors() {
global $wpdb;
 
$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users WHERE display_name <> 'admin' ORDER BY id DESC");
 
foreach ($authors as $author ) {
 
    echo get_wp_user_avatar($author->ID);

    the_author_meta('designation', $author->ID);

    the_author_meta('fullname', $author->ID);

    the_author_meta('company', $author->ID);

    the_author_meta('address', $author->ID);

    the_author_meta('phone', $author->ID);

    }
}
```

Could you please help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't be using a raw SQL query to do this, `WP_User_Query` can do what you're doing, and it can filter by user meta. Also use `get_user_meta` not `the_author_meta`

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for the hint. I went through the WP_User_Query document and got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer after went through `WP_User_Query` documentation. Following is the final query:

```php
$args = [
    'role__not_in' => 'Administrator',
    'meta_key' => 'designation',
    'meta_query '=> [
        'meta_key' => 'designation'
    ],
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value'=>'ASC'
    )
];
$my_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```